# How do you filter data in Python and create a barplot?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, exploratory-data-analysis

How do you create a barplot that shows values that are of a certain value and above?[image: Image shows used phone data]

I would only like to show values for screen_size that are greater than 6 inches. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can filter like this:

```py
df = df.loc[df["screen_size">=13.5]] #Take all rows where the calue 'screen_size' is greater than 13.5
```

and do a barplot using [barplot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html)

```py
df_slice = df.loc[df["screen_size">=13.5]]
df_slice.plot.bar(x="selfie_camera_mp",y="weight")
```